# Wordpress website suddenly wrapped in an iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

A website that I made a couple years ago suddenly stopped working. When I had a look at the HTML, it seemed the webpage was being wrapped in an iframe. I can't login to the Wordpress admin panel because of this either. I've run a clean Wordpress install (uploaded a clean new version of Wordpress and used a new database), but the webpage is still being wrapped in an iframe. You can see it here:

http://oldschoolamsterdam.nl/

Is there something I can do about this? Or is this an issue with the server, and should my webhosting company fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your WordPress site is actually at http://www.oldschoolamsterdam.com. From there you can login to wp-admin and the whole page is not wrapped in an iFrame.

http://www.oldschoolamsterdam.nl/ looks like it is hosted separately from your WordPress site and just has an iFrame pointing to it.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that myself. I feel quite silly now. Thanks!